# Travis Android Emulator >= 23 does not work

Tags: android, android-emulator, travis-ci

I’m trying to run an emulator with API >= 23 on Travis CI and so far I haven’t had any luck. This is my configuration file:

```
before_install:
  - pip install --user codecov
  # Install SDK license so Android Gradle plugin can install deps.
  - mkdir "$ANDROID_HOME/licenses" || true
  - echo "d56f5187479451eabf01fb78af6dfcb131a6481e" > "$ANDROID_HOME/licenses/android-sdk-license"
  # Install the rest of tools (e.g., avdmanager)
  - sdkmanager tools
  # Install the system image
  - sdkmanager "system-images;android-25;google_apis;armeabi-v7a"
  # Create and start emulator for the script. Meant to race the install task.
  - echo no | avdmanager create avd --force -n test -k "system-images;android-25;google_apis;armeabi-v7a"
  - $ANDROID_HOME/emulator/emulator -avd test -no-skin -no-audio -no-window &

install: ./gradlew clean assemble assembleAndroidTest --stacktrace

before_script:
  - android-wait-for-emulator
  - adb shell input keyevent 82

script: ./gradlew check connectedCheck --stacktrace

env:
  global:
    - ADB_INSTALL_TIMEOUT=8 # minutes (2 minutes by default)
```

At build time I’m getting the following exception:

> com.android.builder.testing.ConnectedDevice > runTests[test(AVD)]
>   FAILED
>
> com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException:
>   com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: Failed to establish session
>
> at com.android.builder.testing.ConnectedDevice.installPackages(ConnectedDevice.java:144)
>
> [no message defined]
>
> com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException:
>   com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: Failed to establish session

Has anyone been able to run Travis with an Emulator >= 23?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
env:
  global:
    - ADB_INSTALL_TIMEOUT=8
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that I'm already doing this. https://github.com/vanniktech/RxPermission/pull/7/files